# Import CSS broke icons

Tags: css

I decided to combine my CSS by including other CSS files withing a single one.

mystyles.css

```
@charset "utf-8";
@import url("font-awesome.min.css");
@import url("bootstrap.css");
@import url("bootstrap-theme.css");


html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll
}
```

It seems it includes CSS but font awesome stopped showing icons, because it also references fonts as in:

```
@font-face{font-family:'FontAwesome';src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0');
```

My file structure is

```
/incl/css/mystyles.css
/incl/fonts/font files
```

How do I fix icons?

Comment: Well, fix the paths. What else?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using FontAwesome's CDN, it would prevent this kind of problem.

Besides, this way you can update it quickly.

Register and get your embed code at http://fontawesome.io/get-started/

Or directly at (check the version): https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css